# Exact amount of loop iterations here?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis

What is the exact number of loop iterations here and how do you find out?

```
def func(n):
  i = 4

  while i < n:
    print(i)

  i = i + 1
```

The solution says max(n-4,0) which is theta(n), but I am confused about how they reached this. I see it starts from 4 and can guess that this relates to the n-4, but would like to be sure.

Comment: Try writing out what happens with both i and n for n = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Is there a pattern? What happens if n <= 4?

Comment: loop breaks if n<=4 no? and i simply increments by 1

Comment: Right. So how many times does the code inside of the loop get run if n = 5? Do your old pal Jake a favor and try making a table.

Comment: maybe once no??

Comment: If the indentation in the code is significant for scope resolution *(e.g 'Is this Python?')*, then it will iterate *forever* if $n>4$, because the line $i = i + 1$ isn't inside the body of the $while$ loop. One has to be careful about such things.

Comment: @soka: That answer of yours is truly sad. Say "once", "twice", "never", but not "maybe once no??"

Comment: @gnasher792 lol i'll exhibit various degrees of uncertainty when I want to... but thanks for your helpful input eh?

Answer (score 1):

It will iterate $n-4$ steps if $n>4$ . If  $n\leq4$  there will be no iteration since the condition is not satisfied. The important thing is that the linear search runtime grows like the sequence size in the worst case. The notation we use for works like $c_1.n+c_2$ is Θ (n).

Comment: how did you find n-4? the answer is max (n-4 ,0 ) does 0 relate to when n <=4? ...what does the max mean

Comment: It means there cannot be any negative number of iterations.

Comment: the 0 means that? or max.. can there ever be a negative # of iterations??

Answer (score -1):

Seeing that $i$ starts with 4 $i = 4$, if it was $i = 0$ the number of times the loop would execute was be $n$ times.

Let $A$ and $B$ be the iterations of $i$.

$A = { 0,1,2,3, ... , n-1 }$

$B = { 4,5,6,7, ... , n-1 }$

The size of the $A$ set is $n$, the $B$ set has the same components of $A$ minus 4 numbers ${( 0,1,2,3 })$ , therefore the size of $B$ is $n-4$.

For $n-4$ be $\theta(n)$ $\exists$ $c_1,c_2$ and $n_0$ such that,
$c_1 . n \leq n-1 \leq c_2 . n$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Let $A$ and $B$ be the iterations of $i$", followed by "$A=0, 1, \dots$". `i` never takes the value 0.

Comment: Just comparing, if $i$ started from 0. To show the difference between the size of the sets.